# How to open specific excel file from Blue Prism?

Tags: excel, automation, rpa, blueprism

I recently got an assignment to create a robot in Blue Prism and I came to a problem.

I need to open a specific excel file and work whit it.
My application modeller is set to windows application, launched from an `exe` file. I can launch excel without any problems but when I'm using "`Action->Buissnes Object(MS Excel VBO)->Open Workbook`", nothing happens.
`Xlsx` is not opening.

If I go whit "*Open Workbook*" and after that "*Get Worksheet as Collection*" it actualy pulls data from a file to my collection, but again its not opening the file on screen.

- What I'm doing wrong?
- Should I create/open instances before?
- How do they work?

Comment: Do you simply need to show the Excel application?

Comment: You normally need to explicitly show the Excel application with a code stage like: `GetInstance(handle).Visible = True`

Answer (score 2):

To work with the Excel process you **SHOULD** use **MS Excel VBO** object. The sequence of Actions to Read an Excel file is as follows:

1. **Create Instance**: To start a session of Excel. It basically creates/open a blank Excel file.
2. **Open Workbook**: To open the required Excel file.
3. **Show**:  To view the Excel file (it’s invisible by default). This steps in **OPTIONAL**.
4. **Get Worksheet As Collection (Fast)**: To read the Excel file data and store it in a collection.
5. **Close Instance**: To gracefully close the Excel Instance.

Answer (score 1):

First, in your object studio, you need to use action with "Open Workbook" object using  MS Excel VBO. Next step will be another action with "SHOW" object from MS Excel VBO.

With first action, BP will open workbook, but it wont be visible on the screen all the data from that workbook will be available. Second action will actually show that workbook on your screen.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question for a beginner in Blue Prism. There are two or three core things you are crossing wires here on without realising and also nobody else seems to be answering your question correctly on. PGOAL's answer is best here for how you interact with Excel but to answer your other points.

- What I'm doing wrong?

you're not doing anything *wrong* but it sounds like you're trying to access an application in two different ways at the same time. I'll explain more below.

- Should I create/open instances before?
  When interacting with something like Excel (or word or powerpoint or outlook etc.) you should create an instance because within that instance is where you do operations on the workbook you are opening. For example if you start Excel right now by going windows button - excel you'll get an **instance** open on your machine with the landing menu populated ready to be interacted with where you can do things like make a new workbook, open an existing workbook etc. When you open an instance that's basically opening an excel spot upon which to do some work inside of. You can also open multiple instances if you want to do work inside of multiple workbooks at once for example read one excel, transfer to another excel and update it at the same time.
- How do they work?
  see above. basically, in short, instances are where you open spaces to perform operations of that type i.e. Excel operations in this case.

Now to the original crossover in the question. When dealing with Excel (or similar) you do not need to access the program in the same way you access other programs i.e. with the application modeller. In fact you do not need the application modeller at all and this is maybe why it is confusing to you. When you want to model something you will need an application modeller i.e. when you want to interact with an application by clicking buttons, writing text etc you would use the app modeller to do so but with the likes of Excel you don't need to do that as there is already an Object built for you that has code functionality to allow it to interface with Excel without the need of the application modeller. You can confirm this by when you observe data coming in to a collection in your studio without seeing the file. If you'd like to see the file you can use the 'show' action and set it to True that will make Excel visible but the important distinction here is that Excel does not need the application modeller so don't mix them up by attempting both :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use show action from MS Excel VBO if you want to show your excel on screen. Open Workbook and get worksheet as collection is better way to get data from excel.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Excel VBO one property available "Get worksheet name" select that option under the options 'get work sheet position' you can give worksheet position.for example u want to opened 3 sheet ,u will give 3.

Answer (score 0):

To work with excel you should use Excel VBO and don't have to launch by defining application moduller. 
Below actions from MS Excel VBO should work.

1. create instance
2. Open workbook
3. Show